# Why does my function change values of an array twice in different places?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a function that changes the values of 4 array elements. It does that correctly but it also makes a copy of the 4 elements with an offset of (1, -10). I know it doesn't make much sense and I'm not sure how to explain it so I'll just show it.

Here is the code:

```
void PlayArea::addFigure(std::array<Vector2i, 4> figure, int color)
{
    printCells();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int x = figure[i].x;
        int y = figure[i].y;
        cell[x][y] = color;
    }

    printCells();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Notice the printCells function. What it does is print the elements of the array. The one before the for loop prints all zeros. The one after the for loop prints something like the one I described in the first paragraph. Here's a picture:

[image: Console output]

Edit:
The printCells method prints the contents of the 10 by 20 array cell, nothing more. I just added it for debugging. Here it is:

```
void PlayArea::printCells()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            std::cout << cell[j][i] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

The addFigure method is supposed to only add 4 elements to the cell array. I can't figure out how it stores 8.

Edit 2:

I tried replicating the problem on a separate project and this is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace sf;

int cell[20][10] = { 0 };

void printCells()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            std::cout << cell[j][i] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<Vector2i, 4> figure;
    figure[0].x = 1;
    figure[0].y = 16;
    figure[1].x = 1;
    figure[1].y = 17;
    figure[2].x = 1;
    figure[2].y = 18;
    figure[3].x = 1;
    figure[3].y = 19;

    printCells();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cell[figure[i].x][figure[i].y] = 7;
    }

    //cell[1][19] = 7;

    printCells();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    _getch();
}
```

Every time I change a value of an element of the array it still changes two values 1 column and 10 rows apart. Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: The important code here is `printCells` and the definition of `cell`. Unfortunately you haven't provided either so it's hard to help. Please update the question with more code.

Comment: The cell is a 10 by 20 array of integers initialized with zeros. The printCells method outputs the cell array like what is shown in the picture. I just added it for debugging.

Comment: Well whatever the problem is, it's somewhere in the code you haven't posted. Can you put together a 20 or 30 line program that has this strange behaviour, post it here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I replicated the problem and added the code in the main post. Still the same problem. As you can see there is a commented line. I tried just changing one element but still changed two. I don't understand what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Well it's as I suspected a little earlier, and this is a perfect example of why you should post code not descriptions of code. Your cell is actually 20 by 10, but your `printCodes` function is printing it as if it was 10 by 20 because it swaps the `i` and `j` indexes around.

Comment: Man that is such a stupid mistake to make. I feel ashamed now. Thanks @john. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Everyone makes that kind if mistake from time to time. Just make sure that next time you post to SO to include all the relevant code, it's very easy to think you've written one thing, when in fact you've written something else.